# How can I obtain a zero-filled Fourier transform, as produced by MATLAB's fft?

Tags: fourier-analysis, matlab

The MATLAB FFT function, `fft(X,n)`, can be used to return the *n*-point DFT. This effectively extends the original signal, `X`, to `n` points if `n` is larger than the dimension of `X`. But, with the `Fourier` function in *Mathematica*, the transform always has the same dimensions as `X`. So, how can I obtain the same behaviour in *Mathematica* as implemented in MATLAB?

Answer (score 19):

Based on the [MATLAB documentation](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/fft.html), it would appear that this is accomplished by simple zero-filling. As such, you can obtain the same result in *Mathematica* using

```
Fourier[PadRight[list, n, 0.], FourierParameters -> {1, -1}]
```

where `list` is your signal and `n` is the desired length. For a multidimensional FFT, replace `n` with `{n1, n2, ...}`, where `n1`, `n2`, &c., are the lengths at each level. `FourierParameters -> {1, -1}` is not necessary to obtain the zero-filled transform, but accounts for the different normalization factors used by each program, so that the result will now be identical to that given by MATLAB.

N.B.: specifying `0.` as the padding specification (rather than the default of simply `0`) ensures that a packed array is produced by `PadRight` when one is given in the input.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I had tried PadRight command to add several additional zero numbers behind original vector in the Mathematica and check the results with Matlab. But final results from both are different. Why? if the padding sequence between both are different? In Matalb, fft(X,n) command only describes to add with trailing zeros to length n but not verify from right or left side of original vector. Is it the problem?

Comment: @bucherer apparently MATLAB uses a different normalization than does *Mathematica*, but since I'm not a MATLAB user I didn't know this previously. The option `FourierParameters` controls the normalization. See the edit to the answer--I've now verified that *Mathematica* and MATLAB give identical results.